# accessing videos in my face book profile

Tags: facebook-fql

i need to access to my face book posts and extract information about the **videos shared by me** on my wall.I did it with the grap API,it shows all the information i need but i cannot extract information.what i mean is i need to access videos post by me on my wall and i need to get the link(eg you tube link of a song i posted) of the video.I tried several ways with graph API but it didn't work.so i tried using stream table in FQL.but it also didn't work.is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bit of FQL that will return type 128 (Video Posted) from your stream.

The Attachment Array is full of awesome stuff you don't get via the Graph API.

```
SELECT post_id, actor_id, message, attachment FROM stream WHERE source_id = me() AND type = 128
```